# Sidekiq + Rails loading issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm having some loading issues with sidekiq.
I have a model in a "non-standard" rails folder, the model is called "OpenQuery" and is placed under "app/models/queries". 
Traditionally Rails dictate that if the model is placed under the "queries" directory then the model should also be nested under "Queries" (i.e. `Queries::OpenQuery`).
For my own reasons, I prefer not to do so, and prefer to keep the model under the root scope.

I also prefer to avoid eager loading this class by placing it in: 
 
`config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/queries"]`.

What I did was in another model (Query) I simply perform `require 'queries/open_query'`.
Rails doesn't give me any issues and everything works as expected.

However when I try to start the sidekiq process I get the following warning: `warning: already initialized constant OpenQuery::QUESTION_FIELDS`.

I know that Rails 4 eager loads only the files in the standard rails folders: "app/models", "app/controllers", etc.

My question is, how does sidekiq loads the code?
Does it perform eager loading on all the files in the project, including files in non-standard Rails folders? (i.e. "app/models/queries")

If not, how come my open_query.rb file is loaded twice in sidekiq, and only once when starting the rails server?

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.1 btw.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Similar question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588416/circular-dependency-when-starting-sidekiq-queue